# How to display Passport.js failure messages to the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to setup a Local Strategy and use `failureMessages` display authentication errors to the user but I'm unsure the correct way to do this.

The failureMessages are added to the `req.session.messages` each time a failure occurs but the session.messages are never cleared.  Here is the result:

[image]

Obviously, the last message is the most recent, but how do I know if the messages are from a current failure or a one that occurred in the past because I only want to display an error message if it is a current failure.

auth.js

```
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {      
      myDatabase.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password.' }); }
        if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) { 
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password.' }); 
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  ));
```

routes.js

```
  app.route('/login').post(passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/', failureMessage: true }), 
    (req, res) => {
      res.redirect('/profile');
    });
```

server.js

```
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false },
  key: 'express.sid',
  store: store
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to clear the `req.session.messages` before sending a new failureMessage by setting the `passReqToCallback` option.  This way we know that any message contained in req.session.messages is a new failure.

```
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ passReqToCallback: true },
    function(req, username, password, done) {      
      myDatabase.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { 
          req.session.messages = [];
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password.' }); }
        if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) { 
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password.' }); 
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  ));
```

Comment: The passReqToCallback: true option is not clearing the req.session.messages, but instead (as the name suggests) passing the request object to the verify callback function (fyi)

Answer (score 2):

I'm still new to express but after trying many different ways, I came out with this solution when you want to be able to handle the failure logging in and want to send the error message generated or just send your custom message and render it in your login page (when using EJS for example):

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  passport.authenticate("local",
      (err, user, options) => {
        if (user) {
          // If the user exists log him in:
          req.login(user, (error)=>{
            if (error) {
              res.send(error);
            } else {
              console.log("Successfully authenticated");
              // HANDLE SUCCESSFUL LOGIN 
              // e.g. res.redirect("/home")
            };
          });
        } else {
          console.log(options.message); // Prints the reason of the failure
          // HANDLE FAILURE LOGGING IN 
          // e.g. res.redirect("/login"))
          // or
          // res.render("/login", { message: options.message || "custom message" })
        };
  })(req, res)
});
```